# Text aligned in middle of div

Tags: html, css

I know that this has been explained in several other questions, but I can't manage to center the text in the middle of my div...

HTML code, where the text "Weekabonnement" must be aligned in the middle (both horizontally and vertically) of div "header" :

```
<div class="section2">
            <div class="content2">
                <p><span style="font-size:30px; color:#fdd400; margin-left:40%">Onze Producten</span></p>
                <ul id="nav2">
                    <li class="active">Particulier</li>
                    <li>Zakelijk</li>
                    <li>Alle producten ></li>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <ul>

            </div>
            <div class="product1">
                <div class="header">
                    <p><span style="font-size:20px; color:white">Weekabonnement</span></p>
                </div>
                <div class="money">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The CSS code:

```
.section2
{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:700px;
    border: 2px solid;
}
#nav2 
{
    list-style: none outside none;
    font-size:16px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:26%;
    margin-top:-17px;
    color:#6e6e6e;
}
#nav2 li 
{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    width:160px;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
}
.clearfix 
{
    clear: both;
}
#nav2 li:hover:after, #nav2 li.active:after
{
    border: 1px solid #044584;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 160px;
}
.active
{
    color:#044584;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.product1
{
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    float: left;
    width: 24%;
    height:73%;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
.header
{
    background-color:#044584;
    height:10%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-top: -3%;
    text-align: center;
}
.money
{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ededed;
    height:20%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;

}
```

I really need a help because I've spent more than 1 hour on this thing...

Comment: You can't put a div as a child of a `ul` it's invalid HTML.

Comment: I can't understand what do you want. Here's a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/ug3hLkqL/

Comment: Looks centered to me? http://jsfiddle.net/09hdc651/

Comment: I want the text Weekabonnement to be centered in the middle of the div "header", both horizontally and vertically

Comment: It is centered, but only horizontally on top of the div

Comment: Give the `.header` 100% width. That should work in your case.

Comment: It don't works because that rectangle must have the same dimensions and margins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
just modify .header class :
.header
{
    background-color:#044584;
    height:10%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;

    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width:96%;
     margin-top: 3%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mg7r3xmr/2)

Comment: Thank's a lot, you saved me! Can you tell me how that works? I want to know it for further alignments :D

Comment: parent div u added "float:left" and after in ".header" class div u forgot to add float:left with width(in px or %)...so that div(.header) add float:left and then every things works perfect..

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text to a `div`, give it a fixed height, and equal the line-height to that.

```
<div style="height: 50px; line-height: 50px;">Weekabonnement</div>
```